# Can I make my universal app has different display name between iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios-universal-app, cfbundledisplayname

I want to make my universal app has different display name between iPad and iPhone, iPhone shows A and iPad shows B
Is there a possible way to do without split into 2 app?

Comment: No you can't... that's why they call it a "Universal" App :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Answer : You can't.

If you are making an universal app. App store will have just one app for both iPhone and iPad.

If you want two different names, you can make two apps and upload them independently. One is for iPhone and another is for iPad.

Hope this will help you.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was hopping there will be a hidden secret to make this possible.

Comment: Its ok. Just be foolish and stay hungry every time to get knowledge :)